# Facing the error { TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp' } on JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am facing this error during the plot.

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1= fig.add_subplot(111)

x = dates
y = True_DADemand

y1 = Predicted_Demand

plt.plot(x,y, color="green")
plt.plot(x,y1, color="red")
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel('dates')
plt.ylabel("Consumption in Demand")
plt.title("Machine Learned the Pattern Predicting Future Values ")
plt.legend()
```